# Can't open viewport for graphics in NG Spice

Tags: nvidia

When running ng spice 26, after compiling, I can not plot the results.  The simulator gives me the following: "Can't open viewport for graphics".  I am running Ubuntu 12.04  My graphics system is an NVIDIA style.

Answer (score 1):

This has been an irksome problem for me for some time.I found that if libXaw-devel is installed, (not just libXaw) and ngspice is reconfigured and compiled, then the "can't open viewport for graphics" goes away and ngnutmeg actually works.